# Set python interpreter on a per project bases

Tags: python, tramp

I know i can set an interpreter with the code below, is there a way i can set this per project so that when I open emacs with a specific project it selects the interpreter for that project.

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/docker:root@django_web_1:/usr/local/bin/python")
```

currently i am doing this manually and want a better way as each project runs in its own containers and I often switch projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it as a directory-local variable. This is documented in section 51.2.5 Per-Directory Local Variables of the Emacs manual. You can use `C-h i` to open the manual, or view it online at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what i am after cheers.